# I have a textarea parent component I want to change the height of textarea in my child component by using @input

Tags: angular

How to change the size of textarea component when accessed in child component?

textarea.html

```
<textarea style = "height"=150px></textarea> // height is set globally here
```

xyz.html

```
<app-textarea></app-textarea> // want to change the height of text area in this component value set globally cant be change
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the textarea component define an input property, which will contain the height of the textarea: `@Input() textareaHeight: string;`

And in the textarea.html do: `<textarea [ngStyle]="{'height': textareaHeight}"></textarea>`. More about ngStyle: [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

In the xyz.html: `<app-textarea height="150px"></app-textarea>`